# CSS: Selecting the nth element by using an ID?

Tags: css, css-selectors

This is my HTML:

```
<dl id="id">
    <dt>test</dt>
    <dd>whatever</dd>
    <dt>test1</dt>
    <dd>whatever2</dd>
    ....
</dl>
```

I want to select the third dd but I cant make it work. This is what I tried:

```
dl#id dd:nth-child(3) {  
     color: yellow;
}
```

The style is not applied, whats wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Uhh, there is no DD that's a third child, you'll have to change it to `nth-child(6)` to match that DD. You'll have to use `:nth-of-type` to match the element and which number it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 3rd child of `#id` is actually the `<dt>test1</dt>`, so the selector does not match anything.

It would be more appropriate to use the [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector here:

```
dl#id dd:nth-of-type(3)
```

It is also possible to take advantage of the rather rigid HTML structure (pairs of `<dt>`/`<dd>`) and simply write `dl#id :nth-child(6)`, but in this case it's pointless (browser support is AFAIK the same for both selectors).

Comment: Yeah, thats it, thanks! Is there a way to continue from that selected element? Like `dl#id dd:nth-of-type(3) li`

Comment: @user1856596: If the `li` is in a list within the `dd`, sure.

Answer (score -1):

You could also do it with jquery:

```
$("dl#id dd")
```

This would give you all the dd within the dl.
With an index you can then access the nth element
For the third this would be:

```
$("dl#id dd").eq(2)
```

You can then add a style property:

```
$("dl#id dd").eq(2).css("color", "yellow")
```

I hope this answered your question